# I want to automate the manual process of extracting data from PDF to excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf, automation, data-extraction

I have hundreds of PDFs and all of them have exact same format (mostly tabular). I have an excelsheet where I pick values from tables (PDF) and paste them to specific location in excel (also in table) to analyse the data. I have been through hell : powershell, itextsharp, acrobat forms, export data etc etc but so far I have been unlucky. Is there anyway I can automate this manual process of picking data from PDF and putting them into excel. Again all PDFs are of exact same format (only value differs).

Edit: To add more details these PDFs are tax returns. I have to consolidate tax returns which are filed monthly. Therefore the table heads remain same in excel only value changes for each month because different return for different month. Right now I am opening individual PDF and copying values and pasting them to excel sheet. I want to automate this process.

Comment: Simple answer is yes. Without examples of what you've tried we cant really help to make them work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python has both Excel and PDF libraries. You can find them on the internet for free. Python itself is also free to download, you can learn it fast.

For example, some PDF libraries:
https://www.datasciencelearner.com/top-5-python-pdf-library-know-data-scientist/

For Excel, I find:
https://www.educba.com/python-read-excel-file/

Have fun

Comment: How long do you think it would take to learn enough python to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can export multiple tables from pdf using tabula and pandas

sample code

import pandas as pd
import tabula

df = tabula.read_pdf('path to file', pages='all')

for i in range(len(df)):
df[i].to_excel('file_' + str(i) + '.xlsx')

Comment: Please clarify which programming language is it ? Python would I have to learn python to automate this process ? In adobe I am able to convert PDF to XLXS but unable to consolidate the multiple PDFs data under same table.

Comment: This is Python. Which programming language are you currently using? I could help more.

Comment: right now I am not using any language. I keep pushing my plan of python.

Comment: Python would it perfectly. I could help you implement a tool to do that for you as you plan to learn python

Comment: python has a vast library. Once I get the hang of syntax of this programming language, I, at best, would be able to put together a basic function. How much do you think it would take for a beginner to parse the PDF and export selected data to excel.